# How to work with multiple feature types on autoencoder?

Tags: deep-learning, optimization, autoencoder, feature-scaling, adversarial-ml

This is my first post here.

I am working on an adversarial autoencoder that receives different features, encodes them, and decodes them.

For instance, suppose you have a dataset from a large survey with the following specs:

1. Some (> 10) binary features (dummy variables)
2. Some (also > 10) categorical features (may be ordinal or nominal, e.g., schooling, neighborhood index, etc.).
3. Some (also > 10) numeric features (may be integers or float, e.g., number of children, income, height, etc.)

My question is: Are there any good practices to work with features that have multiple data types?

So far, I have tried the following:

1. Using MSE and ignoring the problem (*somewhat ok*)
2. One-hot encoding of all the categorical features and use MSE (*not that good*)
3. One-hot encoding of all the categorical features and change the output layer of the decoder to:

   - Spit sigmoid dense layer when the feature is binary, then use binary cross-entropy in the loss function.
   - Spit softmax $k$ dense layer when the feature is categorical ($k$ categories) and then use categorical cross-entropy in the loss function.
   - Spit a dense layer and use MSE as a loss function when the feature is numeric.

Then, I combine all this to create the new loss function. (*results are medium*, close to MSE, but MSE still performs better)

I could also use sparse categorical cross-entropy for the discrete variables, but I don't know whether there is a better route.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find it easier to used a mask filling approach. Randomly mask parts of the input. Use the unmasked parts to predict the masked parts. Use separate loss functions for different data types

Comment: Thanks! I'll research a bit more. It seems sort of what I'm doing on solution 3, but it can certainly be improved. Appreciate the help!